# How to resize and load image into android app (ImageView) as per screen resolution?

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-image, android-bitmap

I am developing a Wallpaper app where I am showing the images with the help of firebase and Picasso in GridView. While clicking on the image it opens in a new activity with fullscreen. It works fine for small images (<200kb) but for larger images, my app crashes while clicking on the images for fullscreen view.

I want to show the image in resized form as per the screen resolution. If one device with 720x1280 opens the app the image converts into 720x1280. If another device with 1080x1920 opens the app the image converts into 1080x1920.

RecyclerView ViewHolder

```
public void setDetails(Context ctx, String image){

        ImageView mImageTv = mView.findViewById(R.id.rImageView);

        Picasso.get().load(image).into(mImageTv);

    }
```

Passing image from Fragment to FullscreenActivity with putExtra

```
ViewHolder viewHolder = super.onCreateViewHolder(parent, viewType);
                viewHolder.setOnclickListener(new ViewHolder.ClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {

                        ImageView mImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.rImageView);

                        Drawable mDrawable = mImageView.getDrawable();
                        Bitmap mBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) mDrawable).getBitmap();

                        Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), PostDetailsActivity2.class);
                        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                        mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                        byte[] bytes = stream.toByteArray();
                        intent.putExtra("image", bytes);
                        startActivity(intent);


                    }
```

Show image in FullScreen Activity

```
mImageTv = findViewById(R.id.full_imageView1);


        byte[] bytes = getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("image");
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);

        mImageTv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Exception StackTrace

```
08-23 17:16:33.982 16998-16998/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
08-23 17:16:34.028 16998-16998/? D/TidaProvider: TidaProvider()
08-23 17:16:34.043 16998-16998/? W/ReflectionUtils: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: android.os.MessageQueue#enableMonitor()#bestmatch
        at miui.util.ReflectionUtils.findMethodBestMatch(ReflectionUtils.java:338)
        at miui.util.ReflectionUtils.findMethodBestMatch(ReflectionUtils.java:375)
        at miui.util.ReflectionUtils.callMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:800)
        at miui.util.ReflectionUtils.tryCallMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:818)
        at android.os.BaseLooper.enableMonitor(BaseLooper.java:47)
        at android.os.Looper.prepareMainLooper(Looper.java:111)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5595)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:774)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652)
08-23 17:16:34.092 16998-16998/com.statusstock.wallpaperhd W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.statusstock.wallpaperhd-1/lib/arm64
08-23 17:16:34.224 16998-16998/com.statusstock.wallpaperhd V/FA: Registered activity lifecycle callback
08-23 17:16:34.237 16998-17019/com.statusstock.wallpaperhd W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
08-23 17:16:34.252 16998-16998/com.statusstock.wallpaperhd D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping initialization.
08-23 17:16:34.254 16998-16998/com.statusstock.wallpaperhd I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
08-23 17:16:34.297 16998-17021/com.statusstock.wallpaperhd W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
08-23 17:16:34.306 16998-17018/com.statusstock.wallpaperhd V/FA: App package, google app id: com.statusstock.wallpaperhd, 1:179047417165:android:c116b44eed2a7e0d
08-23 17:16:34.307 16998-17018/com.statusstock.wallpaperhd I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 12780
    To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
08-23 17:16:34.308 16998-17018/com.statusstock.wallpaperhd I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
      adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.statusstock.wallpaperhd
08-23 17:16:34.308 16998-17018/com.statusstock.wallpaperhd D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
08-23 17:16:34.315 16998-17021/com.statusstock.wallpaperhd I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Loading module via FirebaseOptions.
    [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to gms implementation
08-23 17:16:34.341 16998-17018/com.statusstock.wallpaperhd V/FA: Connecting to remote service
08-23 17:16:34.367 16998-17018/com.statusstock.wallpaperhd V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
08-23 17:16:34.367 16998-17018/com.statusstock.wallpaperhd D/FA: Connected to remote service
08-23 17:16:34.367 16998-17018/com.statusstock.wallpaperhd V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 2
08-23 17:16:39.427 16998-17018/com.statusstock.wallpaperhd V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
```

Please help me if you can....if anyone needs more details of code or about my problem, please comment for those....Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Does your app crash because of an **OutOfMemory-Exception**?

For **handling large bitmaps** you should follow this guideline :)

[Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't pass such large object as intent extra. Consider passing just an Uri and picasso will load it from cache on 2nd activity/fragment.

Example pseudo-code:

```
static class Data {
    String url;
    String name; // or whatever
}

List<Data> adapterData = null;

public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
    Data item = adapterData.get(position);
    intent.putExtra("image", item.url);
    startActivity(intent);
}

// in your getView you're using picasso:
Picasso.with(context).load(data.url).into(imageView);

// other activity
String url = getIntent().getStringExtra("image");
Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(imageView);
```

Picasso should reuse bitmap in 2nd call. Also you can do it without picasso by using file/LruCache caching.

Comment: Can you please explain how to do this?

Comment: Thank you but I want to show the image in resized form as per the screen resolution. If one device with 720x1280 opens the app the image converts into 720x1280. If another device with 1080x1920 opens the app the image converts into 1080x1920.